# Loop through itemprop values on a page output as a datalayer

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

We utilize 2 different vendors for our auto websites. What I'd like to do is create a Google Tag Manager Custom html tag that normalizes the datalayer for each vendor so when we track vehicle display pages (actual cars) we can track the Year, Make, Model, etc. etc. across both vendor platforms consistently in our Google Analytics Roll-Up account.

From the [link here](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.quirkchevyofbangor.com%2FVehicleDetails%2Fnew-2017-Chevrolet-Silverado_1500-Regular_Cab_Long_Box_2_Wheel_Drive_WT-Bangor-ME%2F3007469663), you can see the vendor #2 provides google structured data via itemprops. I am hoping someone can give me feedback how to loop through these values using JAVASCRIPT so I can push values to my datalayer.

I could easily create variables using the dom for each vendor separately and create triggers to fire the tag depending on the vendor but I'd prefer not to overwhelm my GTM container with too many variables. Plus, I am anticipating a third vendor soon, thus this might be more scalable.

Thank you for any help.